# Использование гетеров и сетеров в классе

Tags: php, ооп

Правильно ли будет создание такой структуры? Имеется класс A с 10-15 свойствами, и есть геттер и сеттер для каждого свойства, и есть класс B который наследует класс A тем самым получая возможность обращаться через методы к свойствам, + класс B будет иметь какие то свои методы. Разделение на 2 класса хочу сделать для того чтобы не громоздить все геттеры сеттеры и другие методы в одном классе.

Comment: если единственная цель - из одного длинного класса сделать два покороче, то вряд ли это хорошая затея.

Comment: Да, не хочу громодить 15 сетеров и гетеров, а в самом конце потом искать своим методы